# Convert do-while from C to Python

Tags: python, c, while-loop, do-while

Good morning,
I need help with convert do..while from C to Python "while". I spent a lot of time to create good code but my solution not working. Please show me how Can I convert this "do..while" to Python code.

```
do {
    while( c < N ) { list[ b ][ c ] = t[ q ];
        q++;
        c++; };
    b++;
    c = 0; } while( b < 6 );
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's helpful for someone trying to answer your question to know how far you managed to get on your own.

Comment: This is my solution and it did not working:
 while c < N :
            t[b][c] = arr[q]
            q+=1
            c+=1
            if c == N:
                break
    while b < N :
            b+=1
            c = 0
            if b == N:
                break
    return t

Comment: Please edit your Post and add the formatted python code, to make it more readable.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
while True:
    while c < N:
        lst[b][c] = t[q]
        q += 1
        c += 1
    b += 1
    c = 0
    if b >= 6: break
```

Comment: It's work perfect! And Now I understand it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In python you have to work with `while` loops and then check a condition upon which you `break` out of the loop

```py
while True:
    # do something
    while c < N:
        my_list[b][c] = t[q]
        q+=1
        c+=1
    b+=1
    c=0
    # now check condition to exit the while loop
    if b > 6:
        break
```

Comment: `list` is a reserved word in Python. You shouldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: Sure. It was just to follow the question's naming choices. I have edited